# .htaccess URLs title in url not by id

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying tyo change my url address by title, doing change by id its work and show all the content but when trying by title its not show content
the .htaccess code is

```
RewriteRule ^blogview/([-a-zA-Z]+) single1.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and the page code is

```
<a class="bttn" href="/blogview/<?php echo $row['title']; ?>">MORE</a>
```

the link of url is [Page link](http://surya.co.in/blogview/20)

Comment: its work when i call by id but when using by title its not show the all the content

Comment: you should also update the sql query so it searches in titles and not ids using the title

Comment: title only contains alphabets???

Comment: yes i do changes page not found error

Answer (score 0):

Change the rule as following:

```
RewriteRule ^blogview/([A-Za-z\-]*)$ single1.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I am trying this page not open give not found error @devpro

Comment: @AbhishekShulka: just for testing, try this:   `RewriteRule ^blogview/(.*)$ single1.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: http://surya.co.in/blogview/Surya%20Roshni%20Limited see this link work but content not show but when call by id all content are show @devpro

Comment: i think you are using ID instead of title in your SELECTION Query. @AbhishekShulka

Comment: <?php 
 $sql="Select * from blog where title='$title'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$row['comment'] = str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $row['comment']);
if($row['image']!='')
{
 ?>
<h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
<h4><?php echo $row['date']; ?>, Posted by: <a>Admin</a></h4>
<img class="single-pic" src="/store/images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" alt=""/>
<p><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></p>
<?php } else { ?>  
<h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3><h4><?php echo $row['date']; ?>, Posted by: <a>Admin</a></h4> <p><?php echo $row['comment'];?></p>
<?php } ?>

Comment: test this:  $title = urldecode($_GET['url']);
echo $sql="Select * from blog where title='$title'"; exit;  and print this query... and run in phpmyadmin.. @AbhishekShulka

Comment: @AbhishekShulka: plz show your query?? did u run in PHPMYADMIN?

Comment: Select * from blog where title='$title'"; @devpro

Comment: @AbhishekShulka: no friend, use this:   
$title = urldecode($_GET['url']);
echo $sql="Select * from blog where title='$title'"; exit;    and give the result...

Comment: when i do this give a blank result but when try by id give the id @devpro

Comment: when u used this **echo $sql="Select * from blog where title='$title'"; exit;** what query print??? @AbhishekShulka

Comment: Select * from blog where title='' @devpro

Comment: it means u dont have any value in **$title** please show your full code. @AbhishekShulka

Comment: <?php 
$sql="Select * from blog where title='$title'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $row['comment'] = str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $row['comment']);
if($row['image']!='')
 {
?>
<h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
<h4><?php echo $row['date']; ?>, Posted by: <a>Admin</a></h4>
<img class="single-pic" src="/store/images/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" alt=""/>
 <p><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></p>
<?php } else { ?>  
<h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
 <h4><?php echo $row['date']; ?>, Posted by: <a>Admin</a></h4>
 <p><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></p>
<?php } ?>

Comment: how to get this `$_GET['id'];` from URL? please show full code .. and also give me url @AbhishekShulka

Comment: run the query but the title value not pass, value blank go to the query.how to pass the value?

Comment: `print_r($_GET);` and chk @abhishek-shulka